# I cannot test my xamarin forms app with xamarin live player on iphone device when I add plugin to the application

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-live-player

I am developing xamarin forms app. I want to test my application on the real iphone device with xamarin live player. I followed the necessary steps on the link below for this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/tools/live-player/install?tabs=ios%2Cwindows

I installed xamarin live player with testflight on iPhone device. And I run new xamarin forms application on iPhone device. But when I add a plugin to the application, I can not run it. The application is waiting for a long time in the 'Synchronizing files...' state. And then gives the following error:

> Unable to deploy to iPhoneName Player, please ensure the Xamarin Live Player app is open and the device is on the same network as Visual Studio.
> Failed to debug your app.

I am sure on the same network iPhone device and visual studio. Already I am create new project (plugin not attached) and I am running on this network.

I think it might originate from Apple ID and I also followed the steps on the link below

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=vswin

But not working.

Comment: Try Gorilla Player or LiveXaml discussed in [this case](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96545/xamarin-live-player-failed-to-resolve-assembly).